# On infinitely many unimodular integers of certain constraints

Tags: nt.number-theory, polynomials

Given $r>0$ are there integers $w,x,y,z>r$ with $wz-xy=1$ and $2(x^2+z^2)=(w^2-y^2)$ and $(x^2-z^2)\not\equiv0\bmod(w^2-y^2)$?

How small can they be?

Comment: I don't think there is a solution modulo $8$ for the first two equations.

Comment: In fact there's no solution mod $4$.